# libreoffice calc if function returns true instead of value

Tags: openoffice-calc

So I used this function:=IF(AND(C3="P";C2="P");J3/K3*100;"")
and when this condition is false it outputs the empty string, but when the condition is true it only outputs "TRUE" and not the specified value.
I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the format of the result cell is a `Boolean Value`.  Change it to one of the `Number` formats instead.

To do this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or go to Format -> Cells.  In the Numbers tab, select the Number category and use for example the General format.
[image]

There is a similar question over on superuser.com: https://superuser.com/questions/921587/why-does-this-libreoffice-spreadsheet-display-a-number-as-true.